# SQL-Database Problems after importing wordpress database from localhost to server

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I built a WordPress site using xampp and followed one of the various tutorials I found online when uploading the sql database to the server.

the homepage appears (www.esn-hannover.de) and looks fine but whenever I want to click on a link a 500 Internal Server Error appears.

All the files are uploaded and home and site-url point to the homepage as well...

Does anyone have any ideas what could've gone wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Before I submit my answer can you tell me if you can access: http://www.esn-hannover.de/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.esn-hannover.de%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1

Comment: I have no problem reaching the wordpress dashboard and on there, eversything is fine. it's just not showing up when I click the link...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there seemed to have been a problem with the .htaccess file...

i followed [this](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-the-internal-server-error-in-wordpress/) tutorial and now everything's running fine.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

1. Clean install WP on your live server
2. Install WP Clone plugin* on both your new live install & your local
   dev version.
3. Run the plugin on your local dev version, then import the zip into
   the live fresh installed version.

   - https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-clone-by-wp-academy/

Hope that helps.